# Google SDK Divided VR mode view

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, google-cardboard, stereo-3d, google-vr-sdk

I setup the Google VR SDK in 5.6Beta Unity, everything works out smoothly. I click on the demo scene and on the play button for the first time, I got this weird stereo rendering in my game view. Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Official fix until the next release of gvr.

https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/451

Comment: Thanks for the link!